# Issue with Redirect not functioning in Rail 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-2, actioncontroller

I have this redirection in the middle of my controller so if something isn't there, it will redirect you to a new area of the site if needed. Here is the problem. It is just ignoring the redirect in the code. It looks like this.

```
if conditions
  redirect_to "/new/address"
end
```

I can't even figure out why it won't redirect, but I know it makes it into the conditional and literally just ignores the redirect. What am I missing here!?

I am using Rails 2 and Ruby 1.8

Comment: Try putting a `return` after the redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you seeing?  Is it raising an error?  Is there an error message in the console when running "script/server"?  For this to work, there should be something to handle the path "new", typically a controller called "NewsController" (plural form) or some rule in the `routes.rb` file.

If you are seeking to create a new address, then you may be looking for something like

```
if conditions
   redirect_to new_address_path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use rails paths instead of a string path there?

Try something like

```
redirect_to :action => 'new'
```

if the method is inside this controller, or something like

```
redirect_to :controller => 'adress', :action => 'new'
```

To see if the result changes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that a `redirect_to` or `render` call in a Rails action do not terminate the method. Method execution continues to the end before the redirect/render is performed. So if you're looking to terminate execution of the method at that point add a `return` statement. The usual pattern is:

```
redirect_to(<my route>) and return
```